# Python shortcut for mapping parameters to values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function:

```
@staticmethod
def get_curl_params(url=None, headers=None, post=None, curl_proxy=None, curl_success=None, should_use_cookies=False,
                    should_follow_location=False, should_include_referer=False, custom_request='Get',
                    should_verify_ssl=False, head=None, timeout_limit=60, site_rate_limit_seconds=None):

    curl_params = CurlParameters()
    curl_params.url = url
    curl_params.headers = headers
    curl_params.post = post
    curl_params.curl_proxy = curl_proxy
    curl_params.curl_success = curl_success
    curl_params.should_use_cookies = should_use_cookies
    curl_params.should_follow_location = should_follow_location
    curl_params.should_include_referer = should_include_referer
    curl_params.custom_request = custom_request
    curl_params.should_verify_ssl = should_verify_ssl
    curl_params.head = head
    curl_params.timeout_limit = timeout_limit
    curl_params.site_rate_limit_seconds = site_rate_limit_seconds
    return curl_params
```

It creates a new curl_params object. Now all the params I pass end up just being assigned to curl_params.{{VARIABLE NAME}}. Is there a shortcut for doing this? It seems repetitive and obvious to assign it this way.

Comment: can you pass all the arguments to the constructor using `locals()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work; `locals` gets you a `dict` of all of the local variables (in this case, all variables in the function).

```
def get_curl_params(url=None, headers=None, post=None, curl_proxy=None, curl_success=None, should_use_cookies=False,
                    should_follow_location=False, should_include_referer=False, custom_request='Get',
                    should_verify_ssl=False, head=None, timeout_limit=60, site_rate_limit_seconds=None):

    kwargs = locals()

    # if you can pass everything to init, this would be nice
    curl_params = CurlParameters(**kwargs)

    # otherwise, you can do this:
    for name, val in kwargs.items():
        setattr(curl_params, name, val)

    return curl_params
```

Comment: Sorry total noob question, how do I do that?

Comment: To the left of the answer, there should be a checkmark (below the down arrow). Clicking on that means this is the correct answer for your question (and then others know the question is resolved).